# Integrability of the inner Hausdorff measure of noncompactness

Tags: functional-analysis, measurable-functions

Recall that the inner Hausdorff measure of noncompactness in a Banach space $Y$ is defined as
$$
\chi_{i}(B):=\inf\{\varepsilon>0: B\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} B(y_{i},\varepsilon), \textrm{for some } y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\in B\}
$$
for each bounded $B\subset Y$, where $ B(y_{i},\varepsilon)$ stands for the closed ball centered at $x_{i}$ and radius $\varepsilon$.

Now, let $X$ be a Banach space and $C([a,b],X)$ the (also Banach) space of the continuous functions $x:[a,b]\longrightarrow X$ endowed the usual supremum norm. For a given non-empty and bounded $B\subset C([a,b],X)$ and $t\in [a,b]$, denote $B(t):=\{x(t):x\in B\}$, and $v(t):=\chi_{i}(B(t))$.

Then, is true that the function $v(t)$ is integrable in the Lebesgue sense?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Yes, $B$ is a non-empty and bounded subset of $C([a,b],X)$. I have edited the post.

Comment: Have a look at the paper of H.-P. Heinz: Nonlinear Analysis Vol.7 No.12 (1983), 1351-1371. In Proposition 2.1 conditions are given which implie that $v$ is Borel measurable. It does not answer your question completely, but is a result in this direction.

Comment: Thanks @Gerd, but I do not have access to the Heinz paper (is not for free download).

Comment: Available at LibGen.

Comment: I think that the assertion is true for equicontinuous sets $B$, but I am not sure in the general case

Comment: If $B$ is bounded then $v(t)$ is bounded by the same bound. If you have measurable this gives integrable over $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I think that the "key-stone" of the problem is to prove that v is measurable